# Where are screen saver (.scr) configuration settings stored?

Tags: windows-10, xml, screensaver

I found a Ken Burns Slideshow app in sourceforge I really like.  To change settings, an .xml file is created the first time it is run if the .xml file is not located in the same directory.  I changed the .exe extension to .scr, copied it to c:\windows\system32 and copied the config.xml file to the same directory.  When I change the windows screen saver to use it, it does not find that config.xml and I am unable to save settings changes.  Is it possible to use a screensaver file if it requires the use of another file?

Answer (score 1):

A screensaver, as with any Windows executable can store their config "anywhere" in any format they so choose (including the *registry*).

If the program is written to only store settings in a `config.xml` file in the "same" directory then that is what it will "try" to do. However, when run as a screensaver from `C:\Windows\System32`, it may not be able to determine the "correct" CWD or may not have permission to write there.

However, you can't necessarily turn a standard executable into a screensaver simply by changing its file extension. A screensaver is specifically written to respond to certain command line arguments in order to trigger the screensaver, config and preview windows. And to terminate on user interaction.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite. I did give everything full rights to the config.xml file and the program "seems" to be behaving as when it's an .exe, but your point is a very good one. I accept this as the answer.

Comment: I decided to recheck my work by running the .scr file manually. Another file called config_instant.xml was created. I copied both the config.xml and config_instant.xml files to the \system32\ folder and changed security to give everything full rights just for testing. The config_instant.xml updated. So I set it as the windows screensaver, had to make settings changes and they stuck!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Mine are saved in c:\windows\system32.  They are not stored in Program Data or Users.  I did not check the registry but the file storage is as above.

Screen Saver setting are in Lock Screen.

> Open Settings. 
>   Click on Personalization. 
>   Click on Lock screen. Click
>   the Screen saver settings link. 
>   Under "Screen saver," use the
>   drop-down menu, and select the screen saver you want to use.

Use this tutorial to help you.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-screen-savers-windows-10

When you use the Browse function in Lock Screen, it defaults to Documents \ Picture but you can browse to c:\windows\system32

Comment: Thank you. I know how to change my screen saver and make changes to Windows screen saver settings. But where are those settings changes saved to?  Can a screensaver converted from an .exe that uses a config.xml file be used to store settings in a config.xml file?

Comment: As far as I know, they are saved in the default location as above. Converting them to an EXE file?  I don't think so but I am not certain.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for taking the time to respond. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late to the party but here is how I added it as a shortcut.
and it works:

1. create a batch file:

press windows key + R
type "notepad" (without the quotes) into the box and press "enter"
add these 2 lines in notepad:

@ECHO OFFECHO

control desk.cpl,,@screensaver

3. save as name: scrnsvr.bat to your desktop

now double click on the batch file icon and that should work.

Answer (score -1):

I located an XP file called ssmypics.scr, copied into System32, installed, then switched it on. Voila